# Functions that satisfy this condition

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

Is it possible to find three functions
$g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^+$,
$F:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^+$ and
$h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$
such that
\begin{align}
\int_0^{x_1}g(x_1)g(x_2)F(x_1, x_2,y)dy-\int_0^{x_2}g(x_1+y)g(x_2-y)F(x_1+y, x_2-y,y)dy=g(x_1)g(x_2)\big(h(x_1)-h(x_2)\big),
\end{align}
with $g$ that is not exponential?

@Edit: With $g$ not exponential I mean $g(x)\neq c^x$ with $c\geq 0$. I ask for $g\neq c^x$ because in the case in which $g=c^x$ it is quite easy to find possible solutions to the problem, for istance:

1. $g(x)=c^x$, $h(x)=-e^{x}$, $F(x_1, x_2, y)=e^{x_1+x_2-y}$.
2. $g(x)=c^x$, $h(x)=\frac{x}{2}$, $F(x_1, x_2, y)=\frac{y}{x_1+x_2}$.

There are also other examples but all of them are in the case in which $g(x)=c^x$. I am trying to find something in the easy case in which $g(x)=x$ but I didn't succed yet.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  What do you mean by "exponential"?
And what about $g=0$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I edited my question answering to your questions. About the origin of the problem it is quite difficult to explain in a few words. It comes from a physical problem.